# error to validate form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

[here's my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnAOZ.png)

[my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSRNO.png)

this is my code at blade file

```
@if(count($errors))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
              </ul>
            </div>
            @endif
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, please, don't post text as images.

Comment: You're missing the colon in `max35` instead write `max:35`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example

```
'name' => 'required|string|min:5|max:35'
```